# npm never ending process while installing angular 4

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

I am trying to install new angular 4. I have upgraded my node to the latest version, 6.11.2, and my npm to 3.10.10. I trying to install angular-cli globally but it took hours,still no success.
I see many of us have the same problem. I tried their solution by disabling my firewall as well as progress bar, unfortunately, no success in my case.
Can anyone help me please?

Thanks.

Comment: Check the proxy you are sitting behind. Open internet explorer => Internet options => Connectivity => LANSetting

Comment: Thanks for the response @Ali. My LAN settings are set as Automatic Configuration for now. Do you think, that makes any difference ?

Comment: Hello Guys,
I have disabled my windows defender as well as IPv6 too. Still, I have the same problem. My computer is not even able to complete the execution of "npm install" command. Can anyone please suggest me an option to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution from one of the posts on the forum. The problem was with the system environment variables, I had duplicate temp variables which were causing a crash during the execution. I have removed the duplicate variables and restarted my computer, and it worked perfectly. Hope it will help someone.